# Video not getting download . Started to play

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Hi this is my coe to download a quick time video and a .mov video . It works fine though in some cases it plays the quick time video on the browser itself and and sometimes tends to download the quick time video with a prompt. I could not find any solution for this and I want to download the video without playing it. How to fix this issue?

```
<span class="quick_time_dl"><a href="index.cfm?event=location.index&section=download&topic_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.topic_id)#</cfoutput>&video_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.video_id)#</cfoutput>&video_name=<cfoutput>#q.url_mov#</cfoutput>&video_type=lif_mov">Quicktime</a>
</span>
<span class="win_media_dl"><a href="index.cfm?event=location.index&section=download&topic_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.topic_id)#</cfoutput>&video_id=<cfoutput>#URLDecode(url.video_id)#</cfoutput>&video_name=<cfoutput>#q.url_wmv#</cfoutput>&video_type=lif_wmv">Windows Media</a></span>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the content information in header tags:

Please use this code to make a page that downloads a video or any file:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/octet-stream">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=""filename.mov""">
<cfheader name="Content-Location" value="#expandPath('/media/filename.mov')#">
<cfcontent type="application/octet-stream" file="#expandPath('/media/filename.mov')#">
```

This should be written in your event handler or make a separate layout template.